Постоянно высвечивающийся WARNING при работе с Tinkoff Invest API
Начала свое ознакомление с Tinkoff Invest Api, установила нужное SDK для Python, скопировала простейшую программу, которая буквально ничего не делает
from tinkoff.invest import Client

TOKEN = 'token'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Client(TOKEN) as client:
        pass

При запуске, в консоль выводится вот такой WARNING
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1720709423.140539   31588 config.cc:230] gRPC experiments enabled: call_status_override_on_cancellation, event_engine_client, event_engine_dns, event_engine_listener, http2_stats_fix, monitoring_experiment, pick_first_new, trace_record_callops, work_serializer_clears_time_cache
I0000 00:00:1720709423.152981   31588 work_stealing_thread_pool.cc:269] WorkStealingThreadPoolImpl::Quiesce

Если меняю токен уже на нормальный, а pass заменяю на print(client.users.get_accounts().accounts), то все выводится правильно, но этот WARNING все равно остается
Что он вообще обозначает, и можно ли его как-то убрать?

Мне кажется, что варнинг переводится так:
"Извини, но до тех пор, пока лог не инициализирован - я буду писать ошибки в стандартный STDERR"

Это библиотека криво встала. Тинькофф ставит самые последние версии некоторых зависимостей, и вот результат.
Нужно просто откатить версию grpcio, например на эту:
$ pip install grpcio==1.60.1

